# TI Launchpad USB serial comms in OSX

Tags: msp430, osx, launchpad

Has anyone managed to get a TI Launchpad doing serial comms via the onboard USB chip (TUSB3410) to OSX?

I have mspdebug working for uploading code. But to get serial I'm having to plug an FTDI chip into the serial lines on the MSP430.

Does anybody have instructions for making the TUSB3410 work properly in OSX?

They claim to have drivers, but I can't make them work.

- [MSP430 LaunchPad Mac OS X](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/MSP430_LaunchPad_Mac_OS_X)

Comment: I've got an as-yet untouched Launchpad, OS X 10.6, and no time at the moment.  Looking forward to answers here.

Comment: I found the "codeless" driver from the MSPDebug FAQ or so (which is just an Info.plist, no actual driver) worked "best", as in got the farthest before not working.  My TI-Launchpad works great in windows, and no serial communication on OS X.  I am looking forward to an answer too.

Comment: Are you using the launchpad at all to do the programming, or are you attaching the FTDI cable directly to the MSP430 chip's pins (well, the breakout board pins)?  I'd like to program it from the mac *at all*.

Comment: @Jack Schmidt I'm programming it from the Mac, mspdebug works for me, but I can't get serial output via the TUSB3410 - to do that I have to tap the RX/TX serial pins.

Comment: What drivers are you using? All that I have been able to find is that the drivers are still in a unsupported beta release, in which case you may just be having an issue that TI might be working on.

Comment: the "TUSB3410 Mac OS X Virtual COM Port Driver" from the wiki link above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drivers for the TUSB3410 for Mac OS X are still in beta. You should consider contact TI about this and maybe they can try to fix your problem. Even if they aren't currently interested in pushing the Mac side, the more interest they get from Mac users the more likely they are to do something.

I also found a few comments about how there are open source version of the driver, but was unable to find any of them. Maybe you will have better luck looking for them.

Comment: There is now a reliable OSX driver, http://www.43oh.com/2011/10/launchpad-osx-usb-cdc-vcp-driver-released/